# Can't load templatetag in django 2.2.5

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 2.2.5. Using default approach of adding custom templatetags doesn't work (creating folder `templatetags`, `__init__` and `tags` *python files*).

```
@register.simple_tag
def url_replace(request, field, value):

    dict_ = request.GET.copy()

    dict_[field] = value

    return dict_.urlencode()
```

Tried to add it to options - project starts, but still `'unresolved library'`

```
'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
                'libraries': {
                   'replace_url': 'templatetags.replace_url',
            }
```

`replace_url` - is a python file.

`{% load replace_url %}` in html.

Are there special features for django 2.2?

Comment: what is your file name, is it tags.py?

Comment: file is: App/templatetags/replace_url.py, and in this case I get unresolved library

Answer (score 0):

The name of your tag in the code you posted is url_replace, but the tag you try to load in the template is replace_url... is it that the tag in the template should be url_replace instead?

Comment: replace_url is a python file with with templatetag url_replace

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing

```
'replace_url': 'templatetags.replace_url',
```

with

```
'replace_url': '<appname>.templatetags.replace_url',
```

It might need the full dotted path to your module...